# Проблемы с отображением страницы

Tags: веб-программирование, html, php, кодировка

Я начал писать страницу и написал следующее:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Компьютерный интернет магазин Nexis</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:#0F6"><img src="logo2.png" width="697" height="276" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

В результате отображается следующее:

[image]

Возникли 2 вопроса:

1. Почему фон не зеленый в блоке, содержащий `logo`-рисунок?
2. Почему `title` страницы не в той кодировке?

и как устранить эти проблемы? (ответы хочу услышать на оба)

Answer (score 3):

1. возможно логотип занимает всю область блока (он непрозрачный)
2. кодировку файла с html кодом выставьте utf-8. Скорее всего этот файл с кодировкой ANSI. Также если вы работаете на локальном сервере, то создадите в корне проекта файл .htaccess c содержимым AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Answer (score 0):

[@mountpoint](/users/13008/mountpoint) у div-а нужно было задать ширинe блока 1 пиксель к примеру.

Comment: @ivan89 лучше div-у дать padding 20px и посмотреть наложился ли бекграунд или нет

Answer (score 0):

Изображение не прозрачное (белый фон) -> фон div`a не зеленый. Либо, если png прозрачное (png-24) задайте div`у ширину и высоту равную ширине и высоте изображения.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fL2uX/